# javascript arrays in array based on input values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

The following code produces an array based on values of the designated inputs:

```
 <input value="jan, feb, mar">
 <input value="apr, may, jun">
 <input value="jul, aug, mar">

  ####

  anArray = []
  $("input").each ->
      tv = $(this).val()
      anArray.push(tv)
  console.log anArray

  >>> ["jan, feb, mar", "apr, may, jun", "jul, aug, sep"]
```

How can I make it to be a set of arrays wrapped in another array?

```
[ ["jan, feb, mar"], ["apr, may, jun"], ["jul, aug, sep"] ]
```

I also somewhat managed it to do as a set of objects, but I don't need a key at all. Maybe I can strip this object of `key`, leaving only `value`?

```
    content = $("input")
    object = $.map content, (x) ->
        'key': $(x).val()
    console.log JSON.stringify(object)

    >>> [{"key":"jan, feb, mar"},{"key":"apr, may, jun"},{"key":"jul, aug, mar"}]
```

In the end I'm going to post this data via JSON to the server, so all what I really need is to meet controller expectations of the data format where each input's value will be grouped together and separated with coma.

Comment: `<input value="jul, aug, mar">` typo?

Comment: @Quentin Why was this one closed? It is not a duplicate of the linked question. There is an easy solution to this question, but it has got nothing to do with separating a string into an array. Just doing `anArray.push([tv])` should do the trick.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, no, not at all. why?

Comment: @nationalholiday because `"mar"` !== `"sep"`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, oh yes. sure, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pushing the string, push an array with the strings:

```
anArray = []
$("input").each ->
    tv = $(this).val()
    anArray.push([tv])
console.log anArray
```

Answer (score -1):

use the `split` function:

```js
anArray = []
  $("input").each(function(tv){
      tv = $(this).val()
      anArray.push(tv.split(","))
  })
      
  document.write(JSON.stringify(anArray));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="jan, feb, mar">
<input value="apr, may, jun">
<input value="jul, aug, mar">
<br>
```

Comment: `document.write` is considered bad practice, use `console` Object to test.

Comment: correct. just wanted it to be shown when clicked "Run code snippet"